# How can I formatting printed Code in C++?

Tags: c++

I wrote some code to display the result as attached picture.
[image]

My code which I wrote as below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

int col , lig;

const int i = 10;

cout<<"tab x!";

for  (col = 1 ; col <= i ; col = col + 1)
{
    cout<< col<< setw(6) ;
}
cout<<endl;

cout<<"_________________________________________________________________"<<endl;

for  (lig=1;lig<=i;lig=lig+1)  {
  
  { 
       
      cout<<setw(5)<<endl;


 for (col=2;col<=i+1;col=col+1) 
   { for (lig=2;lig<=i+1;lig=lig+1)
     cout<<(col-1) * (lig-1) <<setw(6);
cout<<setw(1);
 cout<<setw(5)<<endl;}}
    


return 0;
}}
```

But the result currently display as  below by running the code above  :

```
tab x!1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
_________________________________________________________________

    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
    2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20
    3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30
    4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36    40
    5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50
    6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54    60
    7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70
    8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72    80
    9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81    90
   10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100
```

question:

I need to display the result as attached picture up and I cant find where is my problem ... please help me to achive the result same as picture up.

Comment: first, i think it is `|` instead of `!`

Comment: and you don't have code to produce the left most column (and the `|`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without touching much of your code logic

```
int main() {
    int col, lig;
    const int i = 10;
    cout << "tab x|";
    for (col = 1; col <= i; col = col + 1) {
        cout << setw(4) << col;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "______________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    for (lig = 1; lig <= i; lig = lig + 1) {
        for (col = 2; col <= i + 1; col = col + 1) {
            cout << setw(4) << (col - 1) << " |";
            for (lig = 2; lig <= i + 1; lig = lig + 1)
                cout << setw(4) << (col - 1) * (lig - 1);
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Same result can be obtain with only two for loops though.

Comment: thats what i call a direct optimal solution .
Really thanks and much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When printing out a value in a field of a certain width, you need to put the manipulator *first*.  Thus:

```
        std::cout << setw(6) << col;
```

Previously, you weren't setting the width of the first column.

When you print out the actual rows, you need to start by printing out the row heading and the '|' character (not, I think, '!').  (And again, you need to put the width first.)

As an aside:

- Don't use `i` as your upper bound.  Give it a more meaningful name (like `max`).  `i` is conventionally used as a loop index.
- In general, write your loops as `for (int col = 0; col < max; col++)`, however then you need to print `col+1`, so in this case, it might be better to use `for (int col = 1; col < max+1; col++)` (but you should still declare the loop variable in the for, and increment rather than writing `col=col+1`).
- Finally, for the love of god, sort out your indentation and spacing so you can read your code!

Comment: Some people recommend using `++col` to increment the loop index.  Personally I do this for iterators, but not integers.